# I'm trying to use HTML img tag in python to send a mail, but I'm getting the following error

Tags: python, html

```
    import win32com.client as win32
    outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
    mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    mail.To = 'abc@gmail.com'
    mail.Subject = 'Test Mail'
    mail.Body = 'Test'
    mail.HTMLBody = '''<img src="C:\Users\tkakati\Desktop\Automated mail\books_read.png" alt="Plot 1">''' #this field is optional
mail.Send()
```

I've been trying to run this code but I'm getting the following error:

```
(unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 437-438: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the single `\` in `src`, the easiest way is to use string literal `r`

```
mail.HTMLBody = r'''<img src="C:\Users\tkakati\Desktop\Automated mail\books_read.png" alt="Plot 1">'''
```